# BluePrism: Tag Queue Item with Exception

Tags: blueprism, rpa

In BluePrism, when a queue item fails, I'd like to tag the queue item with the exception thrown by Blue Prism (the exception caught at the *Recover* block). Is this possible?

My logic:

[image]

A look inside the 'Mark Queue Item Exception' action -- I'd like to pass the Blue Prism exception to the *Exception Reason* input here.

[image]

Comment: Have you taken the Blue Prism Foundation Training? This functionality is covered extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ExceptionDetail() method (shown here in Calculation stage) is what you're looking for:

[image: screenshot ExceptionDetail() method]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

1. Put a calculation stage between Recover and Resume stage, use "ExceptionDetail()" in the Expression and get the exception in a Data Item.

Note: Exception functions like ExceptionDetail() and ExceptionType() can be used only between the Recover and Resume stage.

[image]

2. Use the Data Item in Mark Exception Stage.

[image]